# How to obtain an ADORecordset from XML in VB6?

Tags: xml, vb6, ado

I have a requirement that my program should navigate between XML data source and SQL server. I have to read records from the XML file and have to return `ADORecordset`.

Here is the rough piece of code (`Form1`):

```vb
if (optionDB) then
  GetDBRecords 'this function should return recordset
else 
  GetXMLRecords ' this function should return Recordset
end if

Module1: ' this module contains code related to DB

Module2: ' This module should contain code related to XML

Public Function getXmlRecords() As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oXMLDom As New DOMDocument
    Dim Recordset As New ADODB.Recordset

    If oXMLDom.Load(App.Path + "\data.xml") = False Then
        MsgBox "Failed to load xml data from file."
    End If
    Set Recordset = RecordsetFromXMLDocument(oXMLDom)
End Function

Public Function RecordsetFromXMLDocument(XMLDOMDocument As DOMDocument) As Recordset
    Dim oRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

    Set oRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    oRecordset.Open XMLDOMDocument ' pass the DOM Document instance as the Source argument
    Set RecordsetFromXMLDocument = oRecordset  ' return the recordset
    Set oRecordset = Nothing
End Function
```

It is throwing me this error:

> Recordset cannot be created.Source XML is incomplete or invalid.

What should i add to the XML document? I am new to these concepts.

Comment: You shouldn't expect all XML documents using this method e.g. opening a XML modelling a hierarchy will not result in a hierarchical recordset :) Something that can certainly be loaded this way is a file created by saving a recordset e.g. `oRecordset.Save App.Path + "\data.xml", adPersistXML`

Answer (score 3):

By default xml is loaded asynchronously.
Set `oXMLDom.async = False` before loading.

And obviously, the XML must be in a form understandable by ADODB. That is, it must use certain namespaces and have data in certain format. Example:

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
    <s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:updatable='true'>
        <s:AttributeType name='foo' rs:number='1' rs:write='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='0' rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='bar' rs:number='2' rs:write='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='255' rs:precision='0' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row foo='1' bar='one'/>
    <z:row foo='2' bar='two'/>
    <z:row foo='3' bar='three'/>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

You can omit `s:Schema` section and only include `rs:data`, if you already have your recordset structured with required fields.
If you mean to feed just any random XML to ADODB, you better first transform it with XSL.

Comment: +1 BTW - I was unaware that VB-style comments are now supported by the source code highlighter. Good to know.

Comment: Same error even after setting .async to false. what should XML file contain? My file just contains data like <?xml version="1.0" ?> - <PERSONS> - <PERSON PERSONID="p1"> <FIRST_NAME>Person1</FIRST_NAME> <ADDRESS>911 Somewhere Circle</ADDRESS> <SUBURB>Sub</SUBURB> <STATE>State1</STATE> <POSTCODE>2040</POSTCODE> </PERSON> ........</PERSONS>

Comment: This makes no difference when I tried it using an XML file created by calling a recordset's Save method.

Comment: @Tomalak See [language hints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971). Useful when the prettifier won't pick up correct language by default.

Comment: @onedaywhen You might be lucky then! A bigger file, of a slower read from the hard drive, and you're actually processing an unfinished XML.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried this myself but the following article looks interesting:

[Microsoft OLE DB Simple Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810621)

> Simple providers are intended to
>   access data sources that require only
>   fundamental OLE DB support, such as
>   in-memory arrays or XML documents...
>   The OLE DB Simple Provider (OSP) in
>   MDAC 2.7 or later has been enhanced to
>   support opening hierarchical ADO
>   Recordsets over arbitrary XML files.